# Alter the wording of the "Is required" notification

Tags: localization, css, cognito-forms

In Cognito Forms, when a user fills a field invalidly (or not at all) an `Is required` notice is triggered (in Russian).

How may I alter the wording of such notification? (Also in Russian.)

Comment: If the user incorrectly filled or not filled at all required field shall be issued .... is required. Where you can change the record "is required" to another?

Comment: I do mean "When a user fills a field invalidly (or not at all) an Is required notice is triggered. How can I rename off such notification?"

Comment: How can I rename off such notification?

Comment: I do not need to turn off "Is required" notification. I need to change (rename) the text of the notification "Is required" !!

Comment: Different text but still in Russian language.

Comment: Yes. I'll wait for the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We are working on localization so that the form and all notifications for the form can be displayed in different languages. You can follow our progress on our idea board (https://trello.com/c/Bkd7xPKv). At this time we don't have any plans to allow for custom error messages. I will submit this idea to the team for future releases.

Comment: @NicholasGasque I think this is clear enough (and is enough of an end-user question) at this point.  Feel free to add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We are working on localization so that the form and all notifications for the form can be displayed in different languages. You can follow our progress on our [idea board](https://trello.com/c/Bkd7xPKv). At this time we don't have any plans to allow for custom error messages. I will submit this idea to the team for future releases.

Comment: Our release supporting localized forms (Country, Language and Currency selection) will localize all text prompts, handle country-specific date, number and currency formatting, and will allow user overrides of localized text (via simple JavaScript).  We are targeting this release towards the end of December.

Comment: This release is now live!  Please let us know if you need any help tweaking the system prompts.